# How to measure objectness complexity for real world images

Tags: image, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have multiple images, I have to rank them based on objectness in the images. For example, if an image contains too many objects (even very tiny objects) it would be the lowest-ranked image. I have to divide all the images into three buckets, simple, intermediate and complex images. Till now I have tried with standard deviation, SSIM, MSE, Histogram measure to rank them. But it seems they are not considering the objectness measure. I know there are few works on "objectness measure" using deep learning but the building model is beyond my score for this project. I have to rank them with computer vision algorithms.

So tried method: standard deviation, SSIM, MSE, Histogram, Hog

Please if you have any idea, let me know, I can have a try.

Comment: your post is too broad. please read [ask] and narrow it down to a single programming related problem. you cannot expect image-processing advice on unknown images.

Comment: Do you know the specific classes of objects you want to rank? Please describe your problem in more details, because "objectness" is highly ambiguous.